# Worksheet_Change never triggers

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  MsgBox ("hi")
End Sub
```

I never see the 'hi' message. I have one sheet, named Sheet1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

macros were not enabled... tried to delete the question, but there were already answers

Answer (score 2):

You must put the macro in the right place:

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

The macro will only react to changes in the worksheet in which the macro is installed.  To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Answer (score 1):

Right click on Sheet Name and go to code.

Then paste below code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
MsgBox "Hi"
End Sub
```

You might have not written it at wrong place.
And it will only appear when you will make any changes (change cell value) in a sheet.

Also make sure that Macros are enabled.